# If some function parameter recieves List<List<Integer>> nums , then the nums is instantiated by LinkedList or ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections, linked-list

[image]

Both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are built on the List interface, yet the `LinkedList` uses the traditional pointer technique to build a list, and `ArrayList` uses array to implement `List` functionality . So what can one claim before using the nums will it be using `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` behind the screen?

How I got this question?

```
    public int[] smallestRange(List<List<Integer>> nums) {
        
    }
}
```

Most of The Leetcode Java question has this format of the input. Without the prior knowledge of how the nums have been instantiated, how can someone use `nums.get(i)` function (`list.get(i)` is O(1) in ArrayList and O(n) in linkedList )

Comment: None of them, `List` is an interface and you cannot (should not) assume the internal representation (of course you could check at runtime but should not). If you need a quick implementation create your own restricted interface/class or directly write `smallestRange(ArrayList<...> ...)`.

Comment: This is a very good reason to avoid `list.get(int)` and instead use an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

99% of the time, it'll be an `ArrayList`, and you want to use an `ArrayList` in your code. They use less memory, are faster, and code taking advantage of `LinkedList` can usually be rewritten to use two `ArrayLists`. The main downside is `add()` occasionally running in O(n) time.

> how can someone use nums.get(i)

You don't. You take advantage of the list being `Iterable` and do things like for-each loops:

```
for (var i : list) {
    ...
}
```

this runs in O(n) time for both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`.

*Technically*, there's an interface called `RandomAccess` you can check to see if `get()` is O(1). You probably don't want it, though. Use the iterator.

```
if (list instanceof RandomAccess) {
    list.get(...);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct: there is basically no reason to actively use `LinkedList`, even [Joshua Bloch, who wrote it](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248) doesn't use it. And most of the time you shouldn't care which specific `List` implementation is used. The only thing I'm missing is an explanation when checking for `RandomAccess` might be useful, if ever.

Comment: @JoachimSauer In your own application, it’s the simplest strategy to just avoid `LinkedList`. But the JDK code itself uses checks for `RandomAccess`, to switch algorithms, which is reasonable, as it can’t predict whether application code will use `LinkedList` or not. And `LinkedList` pops up a lot in SO questions, which suggests that there might be a lot of software still using it. I’m afraid there are teachers who give bad advice to starters…

Comment: Regarding "switching algorithms," the obvious case is which sort implementation to use. I think it sorts in-place for RandomAccess, but copies non-RandomAccess lists into an ArrayList, sorts in-place, then replaces the elements.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann the default implementation of `sort` always makes a copy. The reason is that it is backed by `Arrays.sort(…)` which requires an array anyway. Only `ArrayList` and `Vector` override it to pass their internal arrays directly to `Arrays.sort(…)`. But basically all other operations (`reverse`, `shuffle`, `fill`, `copy`, `rotate`, `replaceAll`, `indexOfSubList`, `binarySearch`) have such a switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly predicate that what is default implementation of the List Interface. Interface is just a specification and you have multiple implementations of List Interface like you have mentioned in the image.

Every implementation will just override the method that mentioned in the List interface but their logic will be different based on the data structure.

Now its totally depend upon you which implementation you want based on your requirement. Whether you have space constraint or time constraint. But both will have same method as they are specified in interface.

As per coding challenges platform I think they specify the code from where they have call this method. You can check there But if it is not specified then most probably they will choose ArrayList - for time constraint. And I think a user should not be worried about the implementation that the they chosen. As I told user should know what is his requirement and then only choose implementations.

Answer (score -1):

It can be either of them:

```
  List<List<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        
  List<List<Integer>> list2 = new LinkedList<>();

  int[] x = smallestRange(list1); //works
  int[] y = smallestRange(list2); //also works
```

You need to make your code be able to cater to both types

Comment: Either of them or a large number of other possibilities including third-party code or your own.